# Custom listview with popup issue in android

Tags: android

My custom listvalues are coming from java bean.
I have a popup inside custom list view with textview, check box and I have a list view in the activity. If the user selects a check box in the popup, I have to add the checked value to the list view. Can anybody tell me how to do this and give an example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here are two links with possible solutions

[multicolumn-listview-in-android](http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2009/02/15/multicolumn-listview-in-android/)

[custom-listview-android-developer](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/custom-listview-android-developer.html)

Comment: @Vijayakumar Durai alias YovBrahmin,I did not give exact solution